# DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions (discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

My public bot can't reply to a command since it has missing permissions to either send an embed (`EMBED_LINKS`) or send a message (`SEND_MESSAGES`). I have provided my code below which doesn't seem to fix the issue. I want to know if I'm making a mistake or if my code is wrong.

**Code**

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
    // ...
    if(!message.guild || message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    // ...
    
    /* I CHECK FOR PERMISSIONS HERE */
    if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES") && !message.channel.permissionsFor(message.guild?.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
        return message.member.send("I'm missing the `SEND_MESSAGES` permissions").catch(console.error);
    if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("EMBED_LINKS") && !message.channel.permissionsFor(message.guild?.me).has("EMBED_LINKS")) 
        return message.member.send("I'm missing the `EMBED_LINKS` permissions").catch(console.error);
    if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY") && !message.channel.permissionsFor(message.guild?.me).has("READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY")) 
        return message.member.send("I'm missing the `READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY` permissions").catch(console.error);
    /* PERMISSIONS CHECK ENDS HERE */
    // ...
    try{
       await command.run(client, message, args);
    } catch (e) {
       console.error(e)
    } // (edit) run statement
})
```

Comment: could you please provide the errors you receive?

Comment: does your bot have the correct roles/permissions for the server?

Comment: The bot doen't have `SEND_MESSAGES` permissions and that is why `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions` error throws up. I want the bot to DM the user asking for permissions, but this piece of code doesn't work.